# Customize the text in Facebook OAuth Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am using Facebook Android SDK to implement Facebook Login and access the Facebook Platform APIs from my Android app.

The OAuth Dialog is as follows:[image]

Currently it displays the text: Log in to use **your** Facebook account with...

Is there any way through which I can change the above text as: 
Log in to use **{USER_NAME}'s** Facebook account with..

Here, can I change the text {USER_NAME} dynamically?

Thank You.

Comment: Its not possible. It is unnecessary because how do you know the username in which he/she is going login?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, in OAuth dialog, I have to display a name, which is provided by an user already in my app signup.

Comment: The username provided in your application and the username provided in facebook might differ. They may get confused too. The word 'your' makes the user to feel that it is their account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Its not possible. I think It is not important too because**

How do you know the Facebook username in which he/she is going to login?

If you display the username provided in your application, the username provided in Facebook might differ with the username in your application. If it differs, As a end user really they get confused why I need to login with some other username. The word **your** itself sufficient to make the user to feel that it is their account.